# HP Proliant DL140 G3 not booting after installing SAS E500 Controller

Tags: hp-proliant, sas

The controller is an HP Smart Array E500 Controller and the disk array is an HP Smart Array MSA50.

I have the bios boot order set to have the internal RAID 1 array as the first boot choice, then the CD drive as second, then 'Removable Devices' as third. During boot, the screen shows the E500 getting initialized. If I don't have the MSA50 connected, the boot screen then says '0 Logical Drives. 1785-Slot 4 Drive Array Not Configured. No Drives Detected.' but if I have the MSA50 connected, it allows me to press F8 and go into the array configuration utility.

However, in both cases it does not boot and just hangs there in limbo. When I remove the controller, the server boots up again fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [Configuring Arrays on HP Smart Array Controllers Reference Guide](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00729544/c00729544.pdf)

You will want to enter the Option ROM Configuration for Arrays (ORCA) utility (press `F8` when prompted)

Check the current setting of the "Boot Controller" option. Since this is the only HP Smart Array controller in the server, it expects to be the boot device.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did go into ORCA - my Main Menu only has the top 4 options - and went into Select Boot Volume. It said 'Internal Boot Volume Menu' and listed the one logical drive I had - 'Logical Drive 01'.How can I configure it so it doesn't expect to be the boot device? The server is already configured to boot from its internal drives.

Comment: Please provide your firmware versions of the controller and server BIOS.

Comment: ORCA is version 8.20.15.00, the BIOS version is 1.18 and BIOS Date is 06/03/09.

Comment: Btw, I do have screenshots. How do I attach them here?

Comment: I'm looking mostly for the HP Smart Array E500 controller's firmware. To upload a screenshot, edit your original question and upload the image.

Comment: I just tried but the site doesn't allow new users to upload pics.

Comment: With the BIOS set to boot first from the internal RAID array, shouldn't the server do just that? It seems odd that the server or the controller would default an external disk array as the boot disk and then not allow it to be configured to not be the boot volume.

Comment: The HP Smart Array RAID controller supersedes the basic motherboard RAID in the server you're working with. Most people using HP servers use Smart Array controllers.

Comment: So with the E500 controller installed, how do I use the internal SATA drives currently on the server?